# Python Mayavi In Virtual Environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, mayavi

I am facing 2 issues while trying to use mayavi on Mac OS in virtual python environment.

1. Running Mayavi2 from command line throws following message only and does nothing else

*"This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a
Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in
on the main display of your Mac."*

2. executing `from mayavi import mlab` throws the same message as in 1.
3. Using `from mayavi import mlab` in eclipse `ImportError: cannot import name mlab`

After a great hassle I have managed to install mayavi but now I can't execute any of the sample codes involving `mlab`

`vtk` is installed. `import mayavi` has no problem, command line or Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using the python build provided by Apple in Mac OS. This is apparently not compatible. You should try to use one of the [versions from python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/), which are framework builds. Please note that you will have to install your dependencies again.

Comment: Python that is bundled with Mac has a different signature then the one I am using.

Python bundled with Mac displays 
`Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 12:39:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin`

Comment: While the one that I am using (virtual env where mayavi is installed) displays `Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin`

Comment: This virtual env was created using `pip`

Comment: Oh it's in a virtualEnv ... Then it could be a bit more complicated. See this : https://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonVirtualenvOnMac